# TargetInvocationException - Object reference not set to an instance of an object. for Automapper

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-5, automapper, castle-windsor

I am Frequently seeing following error in Windows Event Viewer – Application Error Log. This is happening on Amazon Windows Server.

Web application is in the ASP.net MVC 5. I have recently updated NuGet package for solution just to overcome this error but error still exists.

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event sequence: 22 
Event occurrence: 9 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: WebApPath 
    Machine name: EC2AMAZ-TUK4T6L 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 9628 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\ AppPoolName 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: TargetInvocationException 
    Exception message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.FastCreateInstance(Type implType, Object[] arguments, ConstructorCandidate constructor)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateInstanceCore(ConstructorCandidate constructor, Object[] arguments, Type implType)

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at AutoMapper.TypeMapFactory.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<MapDestinationPropertyToSource>b__0(IMemberConfiguration _)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at AutoMapper.TypeMapFactory.CreateTypeMap(Type sourceType, Type destinationType, IProfileConfiguration options, MemberList memberList)
   at AutoMapper.ConfigurationStore.<>c__DisplayClass80_0.<CreateTypeMap>b__0(TypePair tp)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at AutoMapper.ConfigurationStore.CreateMap[TSource,TDestination](String profileName, MemberList memberList)
   at AP.Web.Services.Services.CustInfoService..ctor(ICustInfoRepository repository)

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 22 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\ AppPoolName 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.FastCreateInstance(Type implType, Object[] arguments, ConstructorCandidate constructor)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateInstanceCore(ConstructorCandidate constructor, Object[] arguments, Type implType)


Custom event details:
```

Not been able to determine why this error coming up. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Thankyou,

Raj.

Comment: What's the AutoMapper version? Try upgrading that.

Comment: AutoMapper version : 4.1.1.0. I'll try
Thank You @LucianBargaoanu

Comment: Updating Auto-mapper is leading me to many changes in my code.e.g updated version of AutoMapper does not support container.Register(Component.For<IMappingEngine>().Instance(Mapper.Engine)); And also updated version of AuthoMapper does not contain defination for CreateMap etc.
My code is tested and now in live environment. Issue started after changing host server to Amazon Windows Server.

Comment: Then you'll have to add a lock around your CreateMap calls.

Comment: Can you please explain me how?
here is my CreateMap call

private readonly IDocumentTypeMstRepository _repository;

        public DocumentTypeMstService(IDocumentTypeMstRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
            Mapper.CreateMap<DocumentTypeMst, DocumentTypeMstModel>().ReverseMap();
        }

Comment: I may be wrong but I thought if there is any error occur in application, OR session time out Automapper has issue.
Also I am getting following information in Windows Event Viewer – System Error Log
A worker process with process id of '7360' serving application pool 'ap' was shutdown due to inactivity.  Application Pool timeout configuration was set to 20 minutes.  A new worker process will be started when needed.